# $scope.msgs.push is not a function at n.$scope.send_msg

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I trying to create a chat application have to push the message from user-1 to user-2 privately. I create `$scope.msgs=[];` variable to store message.This code is not my code, I took the source code from [here](http://www.codershood.info/2015/12/10/real-time-chatting-app-using-nodejs-mysql-angularjs-and-socket-io-part-1/).

here the send message function which is to send message.

```
                $scope.msgs.push({ 
                    msg:$scope.send_text,
                    from_id:$scope.uid,
                    to_id:$scope.send_to_userinfo.id,
                    timestamp:Math.floor(new Date() / 1000)
                });
                $scope.send_text="";
                $scope.self.scrollDiv();
                console.log($scope.msgs);
            }
```

Comment: can't see any problem add more code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this one---> `$scope.msgs=[];`  , try like `var msgs=[];` . Hope it will works .